# Is there a way of bluring the UIViewController when the embedded viewController appears in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` and it contains a button and embedded viewController. By default the viewController is hidden and in the button action I change the `hidden` parameter of the viewController to false:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    eventDetail.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func showButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    eventDetail.hidden = false
}
```

And when the hidden element appears - it covers some part of the screen. In my story board it looks like this:

[image]

I want to blur the rest, the area of the screen that is not covered by appearing view - is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS8+, you can use the `UIBlurEffect`. But personally, I've had a very good experience with this library: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Answer (score 0):

You need another view, and that view used as background then in your `viewDidLoad` assign to that view the Blur effect (UIVisualEffectView).

```
view = UIVisualEffectView()
let lightBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
view.effect = darkBlur;
```

After you can use your existing view (the white one) and put in the foreground.